# Очередная интересная задача))

Tags: java

Всем привет, недавно я нашёл интересную задачу и мне захотелось попробовать её решить. Вот условия:
Напечатать в консоли следующую фигуру.

[image: W - ширина фигуры, H - высота фигуры]

Запрещено использовать строки, массивы, а также управлять курсором, можно только использовать циклы, условный оператор, System.out.print(...) / System.out.println(…), а также вспомогательные (реализованные самостоятельно) функции.

Вот мой код с отрисовкой (Height - высота и количество уровней фигур)

На формулы можно не обращать внимание они нужны чтобы заполнять первую половину и вторую

```
    public static void renderingHeight(int height, int widht) {
        int h1;
        int w2;
        char pipe = '|';
        for (h1 = height - 2; h1 > 0; h1--) {
            System.out.print(pipe);
            if (h1 % 2 == 0) {
                for (w2 = (widht - 2) / 2; w2 > 0; w2--) { // левая половина заполняется звездочкой в каждой чётной строчке
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                for (w2 = (widht - 2) / 2; w2 > 0; w2--) { // левая половина заполняется пустотой в каждой чётной строчке
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                System.out.println(pipe);
            } else {
                for (w2 = (widht - 2) / 2; w2 > 0; w2--) { // левая половина заполняется пустотой в каждой не чётной строчке
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (w2 = (widht - 2) / 2; w2 > 0; w2--) { // левая половина заполняется звездочкой в каждой не чётной строчке
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println(pipe);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Я справился с отрисовкой верхней и нижней строчки, так же сделал так чтобы через строчку чередовалась сторона заполнения внутри фигуры. Но как сделать чтобы при заданной высоте они чередовались как на рисунке (сначала 1 раз, потом 2 раза, 3 ... и тд)

Comment: поставил минус за обман, задача совсем неинтересная :( и решается элементарно

Comment: @Эникейщик человек решает интересую для него задачу и просит помощи. Постановка задачи здесь, попытки решения имеются, к чему его минусить?

Comment: @tym32167 ну вы же должны понимать, что минус на самом деле не за обман, а за заголовок

Comment: @Эникейщик так зачем такие логические кульбиты, не нравится заголовок - прямым текстом пишите об этом и подскажите как исправить или поправьте сами. Лично я не понял, что вопрос про заголовок, ес честно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задачка конечно для начинающего, потому покажу как решать на C#, на java сами уже.

Сначала определим функцию, которая будет рисовать строку. То есть её начало, левую часть, правую часть, и окончание.

```
void draw(char start, char end, int left, int right, char leftChar, char rightChar)
{
    Console.Write(start);
    for (int i = 0; i < left; i++) Console.Write(leftChar);
    for (int i = 0; i < right; i++) Console.Write(rightChar);
    Console.Write(end);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

ну а дальше дело техники - написовать начало, тело и конец.

```
void draw(int h, int w)
{
    int left = (w - 2) / 2;
    int right = w - 2 - left;
    
    draw('+', '+', left, right, '-', '-');  

    int row = 0;
    int repeats = 1;
    while (row < (h - 2))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < repeats; j++)
        {
            if (row == (h - 2)) break;          
            draw('|', '|', left, right, '*', ' ');
            row++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < repeats; j++)
        {
            if (row == (h - 2)) break;          
            draw('|', '|', left, right, ' ', '*');
            row++;
        }

        repeats++;
    }

    draw('*', '*', left, right, '-', '-');
}
```

Проверка

```
draw(23, 12);
```

Вывод

```
+----------+
|*****     |
|     *****|
|*****     |
|*****     |
|     *****|
|     *****|
|*****     |
|*****     |
|*****     |
|     *****|
|     *****|
|     *****|
|*****     |
|*****     |
|*****     |
|*****     |
|     *****|
|     *****|
|     *****|
|     *****|
|*****     |
*----------*
```